# Sum of frequency of words in a dataframe derived from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have column of data that contains text and a list of individual words that I want to match with the text column and sum the number of times the words appear in each row of the column.

Here's an example:

```
wordlist = ['alaska', 'france', 'italy']

test = pd.read_csv('vacation text.csv')
test.head(4)

Index    Text
0        'he's going to alaska and france'
1        'want to go to italy next summer'
2        'germany is great!'
4        'her parents are from france and alaska but she lives in alaska'
```

I tried using the following code:

```
test['count'] = pd.Series(test.text.str.count(r).sum() for r in wordlist)
```

And this code:

```
test['count'] = pd.Series(test.text.str.contains(r).sum() for r in wordlist)
```

The problem is that the sums don't seem to accurately reflect the number of words in the `text` column. I noticed this when I, again using my example, added `germany` to my list and then the sum didn't change from 0 to 1.

Ultimately I want my data to look like:

```
Index    Text                                                     Count
0        'he's going to alaska and france'                          2
1        'want to go to italy next summer'                          1
2        'germany is great!'                                        0
4        'her folks are from france and italy but she lives in alaska'   3
```

Does anyone know how any additional approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be using `str.count`

```
In [792]: test['Text'].str.count('|'.join(wordlist))
Out[792]:
0    2
1    1
2    0
3    3
Name: Text, dtype: int64
```

Another way, `sum` of individual word counts

```
In [802]: pd.DataFrame({w:test['Text'].str.count(w) for w in wordlist}).sum(1)
Out[802]:
0    2
1    1
2    0
3    3
dtype: int64
```

---

Details

```
In [804]: '|'.join(wordlist)
Out[804]: 'alaska|france|italy'

In [805]: pd.DataFrame({w:test['Text'].str.count(w) for w in wordlist})
Out[805]:
   alaska  france  italy
0       1       1      0
1       0       0      1
2       0       0      0
3       2       1      0
```

Comment: Is there a significant time difference between the first and second method?

Comment: Ofcourse, later would be slower comparatively, you should benchmark for your usecase.